# Изучение С# после Java

Tags: c#, java

Не хочу,чтобы вопрос показался идиотским, так как для меня не совсем очевидно.
Знаю Java на достаточно хорошем уровне, насколько сложным будет переход на С#?

Просто возникла необходимость. У меня есть около 2 месяцев.

Comment: Будет несложным. Вопрос таки показался идиотским - неужели так трудно открыть примеры кода и увидеть, что это почти та же Java?

Comment: И да, 18 вопросов, 0% принятых.

Comment: поставлю-ка я тогда свой праведно-гневный минус, раз уж товарищ так пренебрегает принятием вопросов. Да и о своем "достаточно хорошем уровне" он, очевидно, преувеличивает, что тоже чести ему не делает.  Можно сказать, один минус по цене двух

Comment: Синтаксиси у него и с плюсами похож, я говорю о концепциях. Они могут быть разными. 
А вот на счет непринятых вопрос стыдно, даже не думал, что их надо закрывать, моя ошибка.

Comment: Как мне принять вопрос?
Я не могу найти.

Comment: рядом с ответом галочку ткнуть, если ответ вас устрорил

Comment: там под  рейтингом ответа есть кнопка с галочкой. Это и есть "принять ответ". Впрочем, по данному вопросу подождите других ответов, может, кто-то даст ответ лучше, чем мой - я с Java на "вы", мог что-то упустить. А минус я снял, совесть заела

Comment: DreamChild, спасибо.

Comment: @alex91 тем не менее, вы по-прежнему с гордым нулем в графе принятых ответов. Нехорошо, ей-богу

Comment: Исправил:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@alex91](/users/10388/alex91)](/users/10388/alex91), даже и не знаю, зачем это я отвечаю на столь бессмысленный вопрос, но да ладно, попробую написать что-то умное :)

Начнем с того, что вспомним "скрытую политику" Microsoft( компания, которая создала и поддерживает язык C# ). Микрософтники очень любят "слизывать" у чужих, а порой, даже это самое чужое. C# изначально разрабатывался для того, чтобы потеснить Java на рынке, плюс, это был одним из первых языков для .NET платформы. Так вот, если вы не знали, С# - неплохой конкурент Jav`e. Единственный минус шарпа по сравнению с явой - заточенность под определенную платформу( Windows ). Java же кроссплатформеный. Если же рассмотреть Java и C# изнутри, то станет ясно, что они довольно схожи. Так, например, оба языка исполняются в виртуализированной среде( на виртуальной машине ), имеют встроенный сборщик мусора и т.д. А вообще **[вот хорошая статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%F0%E0%E2%ED%E5%ED%E8%E5_C_Sharp_%E8_Java)** про сравнение двух этих языков.

Comment: >> Микрософтники очень любят "слизывать" у чужих, а порой, даже это самое чужое.

Прямо-таки раскрыл всю подноготную :)

>> Единственный минус шарпа по сравнению с явой - заточенность под определенную платформу( Windows )

Гуглить Mono, MonoDroid и Monotouch. "Искаропки" можно писать под XBox и Windows Phone.

Comment: Русскоязычная статья грешит замалчиванием важности многих преимуществ C#. Структуры, настоящие генерики, делегаты, лямбды, свойства, event'ы, человеческая графическая библиотека (Swing не предлагать), функциональное программирование с LINQ, генераторы, dynamic -- всё это есть в C# и нет в Java. Почитайте лучше англоязычную статью: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Я знал, что есть такая же англоязычная статья, но разве она не является обычным переводом?

Comment: @Francesco: по факту нет, статьи совсем разные.

Answer (score 6):

Если действительно на "достаточно хорошем уровне", то особых проблем не возникнет. Впрочем, если речь идет о глубоких познаниях, то тут, как ни странно, могут возникнуть сложности - в мелочах различий немало.

Вопрос лишь в том, что для вас "достаточно хороший уровень"

А вообще Википедия авторитетно сообщает, что различия, местами существенные, есть: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_C_Sharp_%D0%B8_Java

Comment: Спасибо за адекватный ответ:)